# Flipping Video Animation, How?

Tags: video, editing

How can I flip a browser window in the same way as seen in the MS Access video, which should automatically start at the correct time where the flip begins and only lasts about 3 seconds.  From 4:52 - 4:55

I would like to create a video (that I record of my desktop) that can do this.  But what program does this?

Comment: Many video editing applications offer this sort of transition.  Final cut pro x is the one i'm most familliar with, but we might better answer your question if we knew what os you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do the flip while recording your video, it is done later as a transition effect in the video-editing program. Microsoft Movie Maker has several transitions to choose from, just as almost any movie editor whatsoever.

Comment: Any free video editing programs available for this?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe the Movie Maker program is free.  Downloading and installing it now.  THANKS! :)